# Karma not loading chai-style

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner, chai, karma-mocha

Starting my journey with `karma`, `mocha` and `chai` I found myself needing to test some element's css so I found `chai-style` and I go:

`npm i --save-dev chai-style`

in **karma.conf.js**

```
...
frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'chai-css']
...
```

and also (not sure if needed)

```
...
plugins: ['karma-chrome-launcher', 'karma-mocha', 'karma-chai', 'chai-style'],
...
```

However when I run Karma I see this error

> Error: No provider for "framework:chai-style"! (Resolving:
>   framework:chai-style)

If I remove `chai-style` from the `frameworks` array and inspect the browser's console:

```
window.__karma__.files
```

the output is

```
{/base/node_modules/chai/chai.js: "40e7aa7..., 
/base/node_modules/karma-chai/adapter.js: "bab484a21117..., 
/base/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js: "e188809896..., 
/base/node_modules/karma-mocha/lib/adapter.js: "e8826109cf50b..., 
/base/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js: "1055018c..., …}
```

Any idea how can I get Karma to load that npm package?